# multicol and figures

Tags: floats, multicol

I have a two column document (using `multicol`) and want to insert figures so that they do NOT span columns. I have searched around and the only thing I can find says that only `figure*` is supported which spans the whole page (both columns). Is there a way to get single column figures in a document using `multicol`s?

Comment: @Sorush: Be aware that LaTeX questions with the programming nature are *still* on topic on SO. @bryanp: That said, this one doesn't really have the programming nature. You want `figure` without the `*`.

Comment: I second this question. I would like to have a figure/table **float to the top of the column**, like it would using `twocolumn` instead of `multicol` (which means that Herbert's answer does not apply).

Comment: I should have specified in the bounty that obviously `[h]`/`[H]` for "wide" float is a sort of a non-sense and is not needed.

Comment: 12 years, since this question and the situation still seems to be the same.  I assist @yo' If you wan't LaTeX to position your images, your images must float, which none of the answers provide a solution for.  On the other hand: when using the multicols package, your columns will balanced and there will be no new page inserted, when changing from one- to multicolumn.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{multicol,caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newenvironment{Figure}
  {\par\medskip\noindent\minipage{\linewidth}}
  {\endminipage\par\medskip}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{Figure}
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{foo}
 \captionof{figure}{my caption of the figure}
\end{Figure}

\lipsum[1]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Defining a placement option is not possible inside the `multicols` environment.

Comment: How would one go about also adding support for the [htbp] placement location specifiers?

Comment: Great stuff +1 I was looking for this solution for a while. At first I used `\begingroup` & `\endgroup` for my tikz figures and their captions. Though it was not keeping them together and I had situations where a caption was in a different column than its figure. Thanks again this solved my problem perfectly.

Comment: @Herbert Sir, are we supposed to insert the picture/ figure on our own in the place of "foo" of "\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{foo}" ?

cause I tried to do so, but still black box is coming. What to do?

Comment: delete the option `[demo]` for package `graphicx`

Comment: I would also like to know a way to specify placement when using this method (e.g. [t]). Can anyone help?

Answer (score 22):

"One way around this is to not make your floats float. The `float` package provides the `[H]` float specifier which avoids this" (Taken form [Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner)'s answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75939/182467)

```
\usepackage{float}
[...]
\begin{figure}[H]
    [...]
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Why isn't this accepted answer?

Comment: I tried that and my figure disappeared, ouh how much I love LaTex!

Comment: An issue with this solution is that, having several figures in the same page, it fails to manage space for text. And a lot of empty space is drawn as a result.

Answer (score 8):

One solution is to use the `nonfloat` package.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{nonfloat}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\myfigure[1]{%
\medskip\noindent\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\centering%
#1%
%figure,caption, and label go here
\end{minipage}\medskip}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\lipsum[1]
%
\myfigure{\includegraphics[width=.9\columnwidth]{test}%
\figcaption{\emph{I am a figure caption!}}}
%
\lipsum[1]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Comment: This answer is meant to address the original question and is not meant to satisfy the additional requirements of the bounty.

Comment: Sorry if it's rude, but does this add anything more compared to the Herbert's answer?

Comment: Your question is legitimate. In terms of features, it does not add anything that I can think of. It is merely a slightly different way of addressing the original question by using the `nonfloat` package. I  only added this answer for the sake of completeness. It may have worked better as an addendum to Herbert's answer but I didn't feel comfortable modifying it.

Comment: My apologies, I just wasn't sure. It is probably not wrong to provide an alternative, even though I think that `caption` package works great.