# Insert figure in a multicol article

Tags: floats, captions, multicol

I am trying to insert a figure with a caption into a `multicol` article. When the figure was inserted on its own, it was fine: `includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{image}`

However, when I tried to insert the caption [see below], the caption did not appear anywhere in the article and the figure disappeared.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,top=30 mm,columnsep=20pt,hmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[font=it]{caption}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

\begin{figure}[h!] 
\caption{Fig.1 xxxxx}
\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{image}
\end{figure}

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

What might be the issue and how could I fix it?

Comment: it's usually a bad idea to use `[h]`. Try `[!htp]` otherwise you will need to edit the question to add a small complete document that shows the problem so that we can debug it.

Comment: Is it the *only* figure?

Comment: How are you doing twocolumn, with the standard `twocolumn` option or with `multicol` package?

Comment: The [!htp] didn't work. It was the only figure at moment. The multicol package was used. Please see the edited question. Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

Note the warning issues by [`multicol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol):

> Package `multicol` Warning: Floats and marginpars not allowed inside `multicols` 
>   environment!.

One way around this is to not make your floats float. The [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) provides the `[H]` float specifier which avoids this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,top=30 mm,columnsep=20pt,hmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage[font=it]{caption}% http://ctan.org/pkg/caption
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum,graphicx,float}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{multicol,lipsum,graphicx,float}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{This is a caption}
\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3-4]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

`example-image-a` was taken from the [`mwe` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe), while [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) provided dummy text, *Lorem ipsum* style.

Comment: I found so many not-working-well solutions, but your hint with the [H] really was it! thanks so much.

Answer (score 7):

One option is to avoid floats altogether. You can use `capt-of` package to get the captions.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{capt-of}%%To get the caption

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\begingroup
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}
    \captionof{figure}{This is the caption}\label{fig:a}
\endgroup
From figure~\ref{fig:a} we get nothing.

\lipsum[6-8]

\end{document}
```

[image]