# Floats in multicols require case-by-case manual placing

Tags: floats, multicol

I have struggled with this issue for a while now. Judging by the number of similar questions, I'm not the only one. I find Herbert's solution to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12262/multicol-and-figures) by far the best available. There is only one problem I have with it -- it requires placing the image in very specific places in the text, otherwise, a lot of empty space gets created between paragraphs to fill the column. Sometimes, the column also doesn't break properly. Since the document I work on constantly changes, I need to go back to previous pages and fiddle with the images (try putting them in different places in the text), so they look right.

Any idea how to improve this behavior? I know floats and multicols don't play well together, but maybe someone knows how to improve Herbert's solution.. Thanks for help!

Here is a simple example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newenvironment{Figure}
  {\par\medskip\noindent\minipage{\linewidth}}
  {\endminipage\par\medskip}

\newcommand{\colfig}[2]{
\begin{Figure}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#1} 
     \captionof{figure}{#2}
\end{Figure}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[5-7]
\colfig{figure1}{This is some long caption under an image inside a column}
\lipsum[10-12]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image: Problem Example]

Comment: “Since the document I work on constantly changes, I need to go back to previous pages and fiddle with the images (try putting them in different places in the text), so they look right.” — Why do you need to get back? Maybe it would be better to wait for the final state of the document and *then* fiddle with the images. Even with floats you (or at least I) need to adjust the positions.

Comment: The problem is that the document I am working on will eventually be several hundred long, perhaps over a thousand pages. I could wait until I am done and then fix the floats, but there are two problems with it: 1) it will be a daunting task to fix floats across so many pages, and 2) if I change anything in the formatting or add some text at the beginning of the text, I will have to redo the floats all over again.. For a short paper I wouldn't care.

Comment: See Frank's multicol extension here http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57750/1090

Comment: Thank you for the pointer, unfortunately it seems that Frank's solution requires even more manual fixing than the one above. I guess I need to live with it for now. Thanks!