# includegraphics, space after picture in multicol environment

Tags: positioning, multicol

I try to place pictures within the columns of a mulicol environment. The look should be register-true (even if there is no support for that in latex), i.e. all lines should be at same height across the columns.
When I place pictures with includegraphics, sometimes it messes up the position of the lines after the picture. The pictures have unfortunately different sizes and I do adjust them to fit the column width.

Before and after the picture there should be some space. 
I try with vfill, vspace, etc. but I can't figure out what causes latex to change or not change the positions of the line.
All I want is that the position of the lines after the includegraphics is same as all other columns.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[9pt,twoside]{extreport}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[papersize={32cm,47cm }]{geometry}
% \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

%\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{multicol}
\newlength{\mybottom}
\setlength{\mybottom}{60pt}
\newlength{\myleft}
\setlength{\myleft}{50pt}

\parskip=0pt 
\parindent=12pt

\geometry{
top=80pt,
bottom=\mybottom,
left=\myleft,
right=30pt
}

\newcommand{\floatpic}[1]{
\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{#1}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{5}

\lipsum
\lipsum

\floatpic{2.1cm}

\lipsum
\floatpic{4.3cm}
\lipsum
\floatpic{4.3cm}

\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{multicols}
\newpage


\end{document}
```

Comment: can you add a simple full working code?

Comment: Please make your example a minimal example that demonstrates the problem. First replace the image (which we don't have) by `\rule{3cm}{2cm}` or whatever size is needed to show the problem, then remove every package that you can remove while still showing the problem the above loads `graphicx` three times, it loads but doesn't use `tikz` and has _several dozen_ other unused packages.

Comment: Sorry for the mess. The substitution for includegraphics makes it a lot easier. Here a MWE. nb: the first columns are fine (register-true), then the problem starts.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of `\par` and `\medskip` (or the combining command `\medskip`) will give you, what you want. You can define an environment for that as shown in [this nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12289).

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext} % for dummy text
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{microtype} % for nice typesetting in narrow columns
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption} % for \captionof

\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \blindtext
        %
        \medbreak\noindent\minipage{\columnwidth}
            %\centering % if smaller than \columnwidth
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{abc}
            %\captionof{figure}{some caption} % optional
        \endminipage\medbreak % might require \bigbreak if caption is too short
        %
        \blindtext
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How about using `medbreak`?

Comment: @Johannes_B Thank you, never heard about that.

Comment: Does not give needed results. tried with medbreak, bigbreak, with and without par before, tried nofloat package but same problem.

Comment: full pdf here [link](http://piquestions.com/latex/october-2014.a3.pdf). source so messy that I am embarrassed to show it ...

Comment: We do not need external (unsafe) links to pdfs but an MWE. Please adapt your question. I am guessing around, if I do not know what you are doing.

Comment: the doc is just too long post and the MWE does not replicate the problem well (and is even to long). I can just do it with (unsafe?) external links.

Comment: But I can't fix an error, which is not reproducible. And I can't debug a compiled PDF. My MWE above gives a correct result, so please tell me what I should add with the information given by you!

Comment: Added the code above. Should show the non-aligned lines.

Comment: This is like the opposite of minimal (made me install several packages...) and works perfect for me. All lines are aligned. Take a look on the very picture you have problems with. maybe, it is too big or something. Don't know.

Comment: Can you send me your pdf? In my case it does not work. Where can I show the screenshot/pdf?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19320/discussion-between-user30424-and-larifari).

Comment: I am trying the following:
\savebox{\mybox}[\linewidth]{\noindent\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#1}}
\settoheight{\var}{\usebox{\mybox}}

\LENGTHDIVIDE{\var}{\baselineskip}{\varvar}
\FLOOR{\varvar}{\sol}
\ADD{1}{\sol}{\sol}

\noindent\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=16\baselineskip,keepaspectratio=false]{#1}